# Banno Admin API - Abilities

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am calling the User Abilities Get as well as Put function and while the call is working, I am wondering what the return values are? I have seen "None" ,"Enabled", "Disabled" and "Request". Maybe those are all of the possible values to be returned but I cannot find confirmation in the documentation, just examples of what could come back.

Can someone please point me to where I can find the answer in the documentation or list the possible values returned for me?

- GET: a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/abilities
- PUT: a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/abilities/update

Response:

```
"zelle_enabled": "None",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the possible values within the Swagger provided by Banno. There is a metadata call that returns possible values for each Ability.

https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/abilities/details/abilities.swagger.yaml

Comment: Glad you were able to find the answer to your own question!